# Change default identity Login route to something custom asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-identity

I saw a lot of other threads on this but no one ever said if it is possible to just rename the endpoint route of the Identity/Account/Login to something like /Home. Is it possible to do this without removing the AddDefaultIdentity from the Startup class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Role services to Identity

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

```html
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did It some time ago. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible,

Configure the app's cookie in Startup.ConfigureServices. ConfigureApplicationCookie must be called after calling AddIdentity or AddDefaultIdentity.

```html
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
    //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Comment: So I tried adding the configureApplicationCookie, but there was no change.. Is the name of my cookie important? I tried chaning the default LoginPath but it didnt budge. Is it possible to change the register path as well?

Answer (score 0):

Writing to say that I dodged my problem by just creating my own Login RazorPage with everything adjusted to my specifications. I just put an attribute [Authorize(Roles="NonExistant")] and It will always say access denied when trying to reach the former login page.

Comment: Would be great to see an example of this!